# NaturalEarth GDP and population Data: What year are they from?

Tags: python, geopandas, geography, rnaturalearth

I am using NaturalEarth in geopandas to get GDP and population estimates per country:

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
world = world.set_index("iso_a3")
```

Does anyone know what year these numbers are from? I somehow can't find the information on their website.

I have tried to find the information on the NaturalEarth website.

Comment: The data appears to come from [here](https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/tree/master). Version 5.1.2 of the dataset was released in May 2022.

Comment: I thought about that, too. however, world population in the dataset is about 7.6 billion. which was the count around 2017/18/19